# iPhone, how do I set my date pickers minimum date to today in code?

Tags: iphone, ios, datepicker

I need to set my date pickers minimum date to today in code ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use the minimumdate property:

```
datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 & 4

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
```